# Add column to Data Frame conditionally in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, multiple-columns

I have  a data frame in PySpark. I would like to add a column to the data frame conditionally.

Say If the data frame doesn’t have the column then add a column with `null` values.
If the column is present then do nothing and return the same data frame as a new data frame

How do I pass the conditional statement in PySpark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard but you'll need a bit more than a column name to do it right. Required imports

```py
from pyspark.sql import types as t
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
```

Example data:

```py
df = sc.parallelize([("a", 1, [1, 2, 3])]).toDF(["x", "y", "z"])
```

A helper function (*for usage with legacy Python versions strip type annotations*):

```py
def add_if_not_present(df: DataFrame, name: str, dtype: t.DataType) -> DataFrame:
    return (df if name in df.columns 
        else df.withColumn(name, lit(None).cast(dtype)))
```

Example usage:

```py
add_if_not_present(df, "foo", t.IntegerType())
```

```
DataFrame[x: string, y: bigint, z: array<bigint>, foo: int]
```

```py
add_if_not_present(df, "x", t.IntegerType())
```

```
DataFrame[x: string, y: bigint, z: array<bigint>]
```

```py
add_if_not_present(df, "foobar", 
  t.StructType([
      t.StructField("foo", t.IntegerType()), 
      t.StructField("bar", t.IntegerType())]))
```

```
DataFrame[x: string, y: bigint, z: array<bigint>, foobar: struct<foo:int,bar:int>]
```