# How to add variable/conditional column in PySpark data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
Filename        Type
file1.A.txt 
file2.A.txt 
file3.B.txt 
file4.A.txt
file5.B.txt
...
```

I want to add another column, `Type`, which will depend on the filename.  If there is an A in the filename, add `A`, if there is a `B`, add `B`.

I've seen something vaguely similar to this in [Add column to Data Frame conditionally in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755003/add-column-to-data-frame-conditionally-in-pyspark) but I can't see how I can apply this in my case.

I can add constants to Spark by `df = df.withColumn('NewCol', lit('a'))` but how can I alter this expression, using regex, to add a certain string in some cases, and another string in other cases?

This is similar to the linked question [Spark Equivalent of IF Then ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39048229/spark-equivalent-of-if-then-else) but Michael West's answer is easier to type out and more specific to the problem.  However, I think it could still solve the problem (though would be more difficult to read).

Comment: See the linked duplicate, but you essentially want something like `df = df.withColumn("NewCol", when(col("Filename").like("%A%"), lit('a')).when(col("Filename").like("%B%"), lit('b')))`

Comment: thanks very much for your answer @pault I am slowly learning Spark.  I accepted Michael West's answer because it was shorter and more clearly addressed my narrow scope here, but then when/like is interesting too, I will look into that to learn it better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_extract

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("file1.A.txt",),
    ("file2.A.txt",),
    ("file3.B.txt",),
    ("file4.A.txt",),
    ("file5.B.txt",)
  ],
  ["filenames"]
)

df.withColumn('A_or_B', regexp_extract('filenames', '^\w+\.(.*)\.txt$', 1)).show()

+-----------+------+
|  filenames|A_or_B|
+-----------+------+
|file1.A.txt|     A|
|file2.A.txt|     A|
|file3.B.txt|     B|
|file4.A.txt|     A|
|file5.B.txt|     B|
+-----------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate answer, less general.
Split the filename into an array based on . delimiter

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("file1.A.txt",),
    ("file2.A.txt",),
    ("file3.B.txt",),
    ("file4.A.txt",),
    ("file5.B.txt",)
  ],
  ["filenames"]
)

df.withColumn('a_or_b', split(col("filenames"), "\.")[1]).show()

+-----------+------+
|  filenames|a_or_b|
+-----------+------+
|file1.A.txt|     A|
|file2.A.txt|     A|
|file3.B.txt|     B|
|file4.A.txt|     A|
|file5.B.txt|     B|
+-----------+------+
```